# Specifying distribution in generalized estimating equation GEE

Tags: distributions, panel-data, negative-binomial-distribution, generalized-estimating-equations, inverse-gaussian-distribution

GEE allows you to identify the distribution of the outcome variable and appropriate link function. How do you make this selection in a longitudinal model where the distribution changes in time. An extreme example would be number of drinking days in a treatment study where at baseline the distribution is negatively skewed (most participants are drinking), but after treatment the distribution becomes positively skewed (most participants reduce or stop drinking).